# I/O formatting in C++

Tags: c++

How to achieve the following in C++ using `cin` ?

```
scanf("%d:%d:%d",&day,&month,&year);
```

Additionally how to check wheter an input is a number, character or float, like say if i have a line like `scanf("%d",&a);` if the user inputs a character, then how can i stop it and prompt the user for getting the correct input.

Comment: Will probably help: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note:  the following is untested:

```
unsigned int day;
unsigned int month;
unsigned int year;
cin >> day;
cin.ignore(20,':'); // Ignore everything up to and including the ':'.
cin >> month;
cin.ignore(20, ':');
cin >> year;
```

Also look into "skipws".  Using `skipws` you may be able to put all on one line:

```
char colon;
cin >> day >> colon >> month >> colon >> year;
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd probably read in entire line, or maybe in this case just a whitespace-delimited string, then parse it with `sscanf`... If you're familiar with `sscanf`, nothing wrong with a little `#include <cstring>`, it *is* standard after all...

```
string datestr;
cin >> datestr;
int result = sscanf(datestr.c_str(), " %d:%d:%d", &day, &month, &year);
```

For a more C++ solution, [Boost has something](http://boost-spirit.com/home/tag/qi/), though I have not used that myself.

Answer (score -3):

Its as simple as this:

```
cin >> day  >>  month >> year;
```

Cheers :)

Comment: That doesn't work man , i tried it before posting my question. I am using Dev C++.

Comment: You can't input a literal.

Comment: After this edit, it will compile but still won't work: the presence o  the semicolons in the input will not make you able to read any but the first value.